# Cannot Find Symbol error when using jsp page import

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets

I have been trying to import a java class into a jsp page using the typical syntax:

```
<%@ page import="packageName.HelloWorldTest" %>
```

and

```
<%@ page import="packageName.* %>
```

Whenever I try I receive this error:

> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   class
> HelloWorldTest
>
> location: package
> packageName
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file:
> /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find
> symbol
>
> symbol:   variable HelloWorldTest
>
> location: class
> org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.test_jsp

I'm also using Maven. I have reconfigured my project so that the default output folder is WEB-INF/classes, but I still receive this error.

Comment: show your WEB-INF directory structure with HellowWolrdTest location.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that when your Maven build finishes you don't have any `HelloWorldTest` class generated inside `/WEB-INF/classes/packageName/` folder. If not, you would need to fix your Maven configuration.

If the class file is there, check your final `war` artifact that Maven is generating. Is the class there too? If yes, check that the exploded `war` directory on your servlet container has the class file too (under `/webapps` folder in Tomcat).

If the class file exists inside your app server too, check for any spelling mistakes in the package name specified in your JSP.